# Python Games high scores

Tags: python

hi I have made a game in python were you need to input the specified number before the time runs out. I want to be able to save the top 5 high scores and display them at the end. i have surfed the web looking for solutions but being a amateur at python, I just cant tailor them to my coding. I want to save the name and the score preferably on one line using \t to separate them.

any answers would be much appreciated.

the game:

```
# number press game
import time
import random


print "Welcome to my Number Press Game"
print "the computer will display a number"
print "you will have to enter the number before the time runs out"
name = raw_input ("please enter your name: "+"\n")

print "\n"+"welcome to the game "+name

print "ready"
time.sleep (1)
print "steady"  
time.sleep (1)
print "GO!"

#game 
loop = -1
t = 3
while True:
    loop = loop+1 
    x = random.randint(1,3)
    print x
    start = time.time()
    num = input("the number is: ")
    end = time.time()
    elapsed = end - start
    if elapsed > t and num == x:
        print "CORRECT, but too slow"
        break

    elif num != x and elapsed < t:
        print "\n"+"WRONG, but in time"
        break
    elif num != x and elapsed > t:
        print "WRONG and too slow"
        break
    if num == x and elapsed< t:
       print "CORRECT and in time"
       if t>0.7:
           t =t*0.9


print "you loose"
print name+" scored: "+str(loop)
```

Comment: put up some code so we see what you are doing

Comment: okay I'll paste the whole thing it's quite short

Comment: If you want to display the high scores even after closing the program and running it later, you might want to save the scores in a file.

Comment: Have you read about [basic file I/O](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) in python? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: yes, as I have said i don't understand what half the stuff on there means and when I piece it together it never really works

Comment: the highest score you talk of is it the sum of getting correctly the number that is randomly displayed by the comoputer or is it after playing the games a number of times you compare the scores and put out the 5 best

Comment: you get your score by how many times the loop repeats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this and see if it gives what you have in mind: This runs simulates playing the game n number of times. Then the highest scores is printed out as a list of all scores. Right here I have used `y = 5`, if you need 5 highest scores, I presume you need to play the game at least 5 times then the scores compared and the highest values printed as your highest scores: in the `for loop`. The highest_scores is then sorted to pick out the n highest scores you require. That said, you should review your logic it seems to be problematic. vote the answer if it helps. Cheers

```
import time
import random


high_score = []
def play_game():

    print "Welcome to my Number Press Game"
    print "the computer will display a number"
    print "you will have to enter the number before the time runs out"
    name = raw_input ("please enter your name: "+"\n")

    print "\n"+"welcome to the game "+name

    print "ready"
    time.sleep (1)
    print "steady"
    time.sleep (1)
    print "GO!"

    loop = -1
    t = 3
    score = 0

    while True:
        loop = loop+1
        x = random.randint(1,3)
        print x
        start = time.time()
        num = input("the number is: ")
        end = time.time()
        elapsed = end - start
        if elapsed > t and num == x:
            print "CORRECT, but too slow"
            break

        elif num != x and elapsed < t:
            print "\n"+"WRONG, but in time"
            break
        elif num != x and elapsed > t:
            print "WRONG and too slow"
            break

        if num == x and elapsed< t:
           print "CORRECT and in time"
           score += 1

           if t>0.7:
               t = t*0.9

    high_score.append(score)


    print "you loose"
    print name + " scored: "+ str(score)
    print "All highest_scores =", high_score
    highest_scores = sorted(high_score, reverse = True)
    print "All highest_scores =",highest_scores[0:3]

y = 5
for i in range (y):
    play_game()
```

Comment: will this keep the scores even if i lose the game

Comment: Yes it does. But like I said previously you should define more clearly the criteria for win and loose in your game. Run that code to see what it does.

Comment: thanks for the help verry much appreciated                                                                      i have ran the code in game and it seems to work, however the high scores aren't kept for the next game after its closed and it doesn't display the name of the player next to the score